# URL Rewrite with React Router String inURL

Tags: reactjs, iis, url-rewriting, react-router

So, I have my react app hosted in ISS fine, and I have set up the url rewrite module and my react router navigation works fine.

My issue is, 
HomeSite/Searchpage I have a table with search results.

When user clicks on one of the results, it will navigate to i.e.
https://www.site/LWM2/Detail/[itemid]

and then on my detail page it gets [itemid] from url to populate information on the page. via
const { [itemid] } = useParams();

How do I set up rules in Url Rewrite to have it go to detail page and preserve the [itemid] information

Current rules:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<configuration>  
    <system.webServer>  
        <rewrite>  
            <rules>
                <rule name="RemoveTrailingSlashRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)/$" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
                </rule>  
                <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">  
                    <match url=".*" />  
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />  
                    </conditions>  
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/LWM2/" appendQueryString="false" />  
                </rule>  
            </rules>  
        </rewrite>  
    </system.webServer>  
</configuration>
```

Comment: You wish to navigate to the new URL with the specific [ItemID] when clicking the search result, is that correct? I think this functionality should be accomplished by the React itself other than URL rewrite. Likewise, Getting the [ItemID] to populate the form on the page is a process of data binding. As long as we have configured the react route properly. the form with the right field name will be populated properly per the URL string.

Comment: Well it DOES work itself within react. It's when I take the app and host it on IIS that it doesn't work.